# What kind of errors are returned by HttpServer stream in Dart

Tags: dart, exception, dart-server

I'm going through the [Dart server documentation](https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/httpserver). I see I can `await for` an HttpRequest like this:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

Future main() async {
  var server = await HttpServer.bind(
    InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4,
    4040,
  );
  print('Listening on localhost:${server.port}');

  await for (HttpRequest request in server) {
    request.response.write('Hello, world!');
    await request.response.close();
  }
}
```

That's because HttpServer implements Stream. But since a stream can return either a value or an error, I should catch exceptions like this, right:

```dart
try {
  await for (HttpRequest request in server) {
    request.response.write('Hello, world!');
    await request.response.close();
  }
} catch (e) {
  // ???
}
```

But I'm not sure what kind of exceptions can be caught. Do the exceptions arise from the request (and warrant a 400 level response) or from the server (and warrant a 500 level response)? Or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Error status codes

On exception, a **BAD_REQUEST** status code will be set:

```dart
    } catch (e) {
      // Try to send BAD_REQUEST response.
      request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.badRequest;
```

<sup>(see [source](https://github.com/dart-lang/http_server/blob/129555e4975a7d5a48eb48f61f2cefe885b3f496/lib/src/http_body.dart#L123))</sup>

That would be ***`400`*** (see [`badRequest`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-io/HttpStatus/badRequest-constant.html)).

### Stream errors

[In that same `catch` block](https://github.com/dart-lang/http_server/blob/129555e4975a7d5a48eb48f61f2cefe885b3f496/lib/src/http_body.dart#L125), the exceptions will be `rethrow`n, which means that you will still receive all the errors on your stream. This happens in [`processRequest`](https://github.com/dart-lang/http_server/blob/129555e4975a7d5a48eb48f61f2cefe885b3f496/lib/src/http_body.dart#L116), which processes all requests in `bind`.
And you get the errors on your stream because they are [forwarded to the sink in `bind`](https://github.com/dart-lang/http_server/blob/129555e4975a7d5a48eb48f61f2cefe885b3f496/lib/src/http_body.dart#L151).

#### Kinds of errors

I could only find a single **explicit** exception type:

```dart
    if (disposition == null) {
      throw const HttpException(
          "Mime Multipart doesn't contain a Content-Disposition header value");
    }
    if (encoding != null &&
        !_transparentEncodings.contains(encoding.value.toLowerCase())) {
      // TODO(ajohnsen): Support BASE64, etc.
      throw HttpException('Unsupported contentTransferEncoding: '
          '${encoding.value}');
    }
```

(see [source](https://github.com/dart-lang/http_server/blob/129555e4975a7d5a48eb48f61f2cefe885b3f496/lib/src/http_multipart_form_data.dart#L92))

These are both [`HttpException`s](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-io/HttpException-class.html).

Comment: Very useful! Thank you. That's interesting that the framework itself tries to return a BAD_REQUEST and close the response. I was thinking I would have to do that myself.